# Django Page not found (404) Request Method: No Sales matches the given query

Tags: python, html, django

My python code keeps returning the following error:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/geo_gas/edit_sale/ Raised by:
>     geo_gas.views.edit_sale No Sales matches the given query.

```
class Sales(models.Model):
        gas_qty = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        amount = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
            return self.gas_qty

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Sales'
```

View.py

```
    def edit_sale(request):
        """Edit an existing sales record."""
        entry = get_object_or_404(Sales, pk=1)

        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = SalesForm(instance=entry)
        else:
            form = SalesForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('geo_gas:sales'))

        context = {'entry': entry, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'ht/edit_sale.html', context)
```

Urls.py

```
    .......

    # Page for editing a sale entry
        path('edit_sale/', views.edit_sale, name='edit_sale'),

    .......
```

ht/templates/ht/edit_sale.html

Edit entry:

```
             <form action="{% url 'geo_gas:edit_entry' %}" method='post'>

            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form.as_p }}

        <button name="submit">save changes</button>

         </form>
```

I have not been able to identify what part of the code is causing the error to occur.

Comment: did you add the namespace `geo_gas` ?

Comment: Can you share the detailed version of `urls.py`?

Comment: post your complete `urls.py`. Where this url `'geo_gas:sales'` is defined?

Comment: Try different id, that exists in your db `entry = get_object_or_404(Sales, pk=1)` instead of one. i guess you have deleted some of instance

Comment: You are hardcoding `pk=1` in your view, so you're going to get an error if that doesn't exist. I showed you how to add the primary key to the url and view in your question yesterday -
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48426092/113962

Comment: you have to make your url dynamic, by passing a parameter and calling it in your view, ex: path('articles/(?P<pk>\w+)/', views.special_case_2003), and in your view:  def edit_sale(request, pk):

Comment: @NitaAlexandru you shouldn't use regexes with `path()`.

Comment: path('edit_sale/(?P<pk>\w+)/ is returning- - NoReverseMatch at /geo_gas/sale/

Comment: @Alasdair now i've seen their example

Comment: @ChineduObi don't use regexes like `\w+` in path. As I said, I already wrote how to change your code in my answer yesterday - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48426092/113962

Comment: @Alasdair, I used the same syntax on other functions, which returns a value per query .

Comment: Trust me, using `\w+` inside `path()` is incorrect - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334486/#47334557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that no Sales instance with pk=1 exists, as the error is likely thrown by `get_object_or_404(Sales, pk=1)`. So you might want to check if that's really the case.

You can try checking the pk of your instance by doing `Sales.objects.first().pk` to see.

**Update: How to make it dynamic**

Before going into that, it might be useful to understand what RESTful API endpoints are like. But briefly in this context you might want to have something like this

```
# urls.py
path('sale/', views.list_sale, name='list_sale'),
path('sale/<int:pk>/', views.retrieve_update_delete_sale, name='retrieve_update_delete_sale')  # names of the view can be whatever you want
```

What happens here is that the `pk` argument is passed from the URL (`<int:pk>`) to the view as an argument in the function-based view.

**Accessing the arguments passed from URLs in your view**

```
def retrieve_update_delete_sale(request, pk):  # <-- you will be able to access it here
    """Edit an existing sales record."""
    entry = get_object_or_404(Sales, pk=pk)  # this is now dynamic!

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = SalesForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        form = SalesForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('geo_gas:sales'))

    context = {'entry': entry, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'ht/edit_sale.html', context)
```

So now if you want to access the Sale instance with `pk=1`, all you need to do is visit the url with `/sale/1/`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas Jiang. How can I make dynamic?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Hi @Thomas Jiang, I implemented as suggested. please check
urls.py
 path('sale/<int:pk>/', views.retrieve_update_delete_sale, name='retrieve_update_delete_sale'),

html --> <form action="{% url 'geo_gas:retrieve_update_delete_sale' %}" method='post'>  

Reverse for 'retrieve_update_delete_sale' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['geo_gas\\/sale\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']